# Is it possible to use bcrypt or scrypt as an alternative to PBKDF2 in SJCL?

Tags: javascript, bcrypt, scrypt, sjcl

I've been using the library and I really like it, but from what I have read PBKDF2 is a bit more vulnerable to brute force attacks than bcrypt or scrypt. I came across this issue about [adding scrypt support](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/issues/122), but there doesn't seem to be a clear answer.

Ideally, I would like to simply drop in a replacement for the PBKDF2 functionality, but I'm not familiar enough with SJCL's inner workings to know if this is possible.

If it was possible, you could use something like this [pure JS bcrypt](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js) implementation fairly easily I would imagine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that is possible but needs more manual work.
First you need to compile sjcl with scrypt:

```
./configure --with-scrypt
make
```

Then you will have to use scrypt to generate a key pair:

```
var salt = sjcl.random.randomWords(2,0);
var key = sjcl.misc.scrypt(password, salt);
var encrypted = sjcl.json.encrypt(key, original);
var decrypted = sjcl.json.decrypt(key, encrypted);
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answer. I'm going to give this a try later. Is there a way to set the number of rounds or work factor for scrypt?

Comment: Just for anyone else who finds this. Apparently, passing the second `0` argument to `sjcl.random.randomWords` is for testing purposes only and will [severely cripple](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/issues/77) the security of the resulting key. I'm not sure how much it matters in this context given that it is being used for a salt, but I will leave that to people more knowledgeable than me.

Comment: A salt, same as an IV has to only be non-repeating and not as random as a key, so `sjcl.random.randomWords` with the second argument 0 should be fine. It is also what sjcl uses internally for pbkdf2.

Comment: In regards of setting the work factor for scrypt, just look into the documentation in the scrypt file here: https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/blob/master/core/scrypt.js

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That is very helpful.